# Non-deterministic 2-tape Turing Machine that recognizes palindromes in linear time

Tags: turing-machines, nondeterminism

This question is taken from an exam of a Computer Theory Course.

> Describe how a NON-Deterministic Turing Machine with two tapes recognize in **linear** time palindrome strings with **even** length that have the form: $L=\{ww^R\mid w\in\{a,b\}^+\}$.

- Tape 1: Read-Only & monodirectional
- Tape 2: Read and Write, bidirectional

$w^R$ is the reverse of $w$.

**My guess:**

*With determinism* and  $L = \{{wcw^R | w \in \{a,b\}^+ \}}$ I copy the input from tape 1 onto tape 2, then I check if the first part of the tape is equals to second part using two markers, $X$ for $a$ and $Y$ for $b$ to keep track of the current iteration.

In every iteration of the algorithm I check if there is a corresponding $a$ (or $b$) in the second part of the tape, reading the tape backwards.

In the last iteration, if i read only $X$ or $Y$ i accept, otherwise reject.

*With non-determinism*: i need to guess where is the center of the tape. One of the configuration in the computation tree would be $wq_cw^R$ where $q_c$ identify the state representing the string's center. Here i can do the same verification for the deterministic version of the problem.

Comment: Is this exam currently ongoing, or is this a past exam that you are studying from?

Comment: It is a question given 1 years ago

Comment: Do you have permission from the professor to post the exam question online for the whole world to see?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Suppose that, instead, the alphabet was $\{a,b,c\}$ you wanted to recognize

$$\{wcw^{\mathrm{R}}\mid w\in\{a,b\}^+\}\,.$$

How would you do that on a deterministic version of the machine you're trying to use?  Now, in the real problem, nobody's telling you where the middle of the string is.  How would you use nondeterminism to get around that problem?

Comment: i made some edits in the question's body after your hint. Thanks!

Comment: Well, that's fine but we're not here to grade your attempts.

Comment: What could happen if the string is odd?

Comment: @Jack Then no computation path will match the two "halves" of the string, since they have different lengths.

Comment: Reading your comment, another question comes to mind. What if i have to recognize all palindrome strings over the whole $\Sigma^*$ ? I just made another question here: [Limited Turing Machine for Palindromes](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83623/non-deterministic-limited-turing-machine-that-recognize-the-language-p-of-pali)

Comment: It makes no difference what the alphabet is. To recognize palindromes over $\Sigma^*$, invent an arbitrary new symbol $\oplus$ that's not in $\Sigma$ and consider recognizing strings $w\oplus w^{\mathrm{R}}$ over alphabet $\Sigma\cup\{\oplus\}$. Then use nondeterminism to find the middle of the string, instead of the new character.

Comment: @Jack Oops, yes. I deleted the comment and reposted a correct version. (It was too old to edit but it's confusing to have incorrect comments.)

Comment: I still don't get it. If the first tape is read-only, do I have to copy the string two times on the second tape and add the $\oplus$ symbol to it? So for example

Tape1: ABBA$\square$
Tape 2: ABBA$\oplus$ABBA

Then use non-determinism on second tape?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68382/discussion-between-jack-and-david-richerby).